# Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data when requesting Institution Data

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, ethereumjs

I am trying to request for Institution details which returns two or more data but getting these error.

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data
    at Institution.getInstituteData (contracts/Institution.sol:112)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at HardhatNode.runCall (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:713:20)
    at EthModule._callAction (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:365:9)
    at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:124:18)
    at staticCallResult (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:337:22)
    at staticCall (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:303:24)
    at Proxy.getInstituteData (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:351:41)
```

Here is my Institution.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

import "./Certification.sol";

error NotOwner();

contract Institution {
    // State Variables
    address public owner;

    // Mappings
    mapping(address => Institute) private institutes; // Institutes Mapping
    mapping(address => Course[]) private instituteCourses; // Courses Mapping

    // Events
    event instituteAdded(string _instituteName);

    // Modifier
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Course {
        string course_name;
        string course_code;
        // Other attributes can be added
    }

    struct Institute {
        string institute_name;
        string institute_acronym;
        string institute_link;
    }

    function stringToBytes32(
        string memory source
    ) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }

    function addInstitute(
        address _address,
        string memory _institute_name,
        string memory _institute_acronym,
        string memory _institute_link,
        Course[] memory _institute_courses
    ) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(
            institutes[_address].institute_name
        );
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length == 0,
            "Institute with token already exists"
        );
        require(
            _institute_courses.length > 0,
            "Atleast one course must be added"
        );
        institutes[_address] = Institute(
            _institute_name,
            _institute_acronym,
            _institute_link
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _institute_courses.length; i++) {
            instituteCourses[_address].push(_institute_courses[i]);
        }

        emit instituteAdded(_institute_name);
    }

    // Called by Institutions
    // function getInstituteData()
    //     public
    //     view
    //     returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    // {
    //     Institute memory temp = institutes[msg.sender];
    //     bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
    //     require(
    //         tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
    //         "Institute account does not exist!"
    //     );
    //     return (
    //         temp.institute_name,
    //         temp.institute_acronym,
    //         temp.institute_link,
    //         instituteCourses[msg.sender]
    //     );
    // }

    // Called by Smart Contracts
    function getInstituteData(
        address _address
    )
        public
        view
        returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    {
        require(
            Certification(msg.sender).owner() == owner,
            "Incorrect smart contract & authorizations!"
        );
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
            "Institute does not exist!"
        );
        return (
            temp.institute_name,
            temp.institute_acronym,
            temp.institute_link,
            instituteCourses[_address]
        );
    }

    function checkInstitutePermission(
        address _address
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        if (tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test file

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Institution Contract", function () {
  let mockOwner_acc,
    mockInstitute_acc,
    mockInvalid_acc,
    mockInstitute,
    mockInstitute_course,
    institution,
    certification;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    mockOwner_acc = accounts[0];
    mockInstitute_acc = accounts[1];
    mockInvalid_acc = accounts[2];

    mockInstitute = {
      institute_name: "Heritage Institute of Technology",
      institute_acronym: "HITK",
      institute_link: "www.heritageit.edu",
    };

    mockInstitute_course = [
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Engineering",
        course_code: "CSE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Electronics and Communication Engineering",
        course_code: "ECE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Business Studies",
        course_code: "CSBS",
      },
    ];

    const Institution = await ethers.getContractFactory("Institution");
    institution = await Institution.deploy({
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });

    institution_address = await institution.getAddress();

    const Certification = await ethers.getContractFactory("Certification");
    certification = await Certification.deploy(await institution.getAddress(), {
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });
  });

  describe("Deployment of Institution Contract", () => {
    it("It has correct owner", async function () {
      const instituteContract_owner = await institution.owner();
      assert.equal(instituteContract_owner, mockOwner_acc.address);
    });
  });

  describe("Adding institute", () => {
    it("Only owner can add Institute, others cannot add", async function () {
      const attackerConnectedAccounts = await institution.connect(
        mockInvalid_acc
      );
      await expect(
        attackerConnectedAccounts.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstitute_course
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(attackerConnectedAccounts, "NotOwner");
    });

    it("Adds an institute with valid details", async function () {
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      const { events, logs } = await receipt.wait();

      // console.log(logs[0].fragment.name);
      // console.log(logs[0].args._instituteName);

      assert.equal(logs.length, 1);
      assert.equal(logs[0].fragment.name, "instituteAdded");
      assert.equal(logs[0].args._instituteName, mockInstitute.institute_name);
    });

    it("Fails if Institute already existed", async function () {
      // const institution2 = await Institution.new({ from: mockOwner_acc });
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstitute_course,
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Institute with token already exists");
    });

    it("Checks atleast one course is added or not", async function () {
      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          [],
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Atleast one course must be added");
    });
  });

  describe("Fetching Institute Data", () => {
    it("Only owner can request for Institute Data", async function () {
      const institute_data = await institution.getInstituteData(
        mockInstitute_acc.address
        // { from: await certification.getAddress() }
      );
      assert.equal(institute_data[0], mockInstitute.institute_name);
      assert.equal(institute_data[1], mockInstitute.institute_acronym);
      assert.equal(institute_data[2], mockInstitute.institute_link);

      const formattedInstituteCoursesData = institute_data[3].map((x) => {
        return { course_name: x.course_name };
      });
      assert.equal(
        JSON.stringify(formattedInstituteCoursesData),
        JSON.stringify(mockInstituteCourses),
        "the courses of the institute is incorrect"
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your `hardhat.config.js` file?

Comment: Nikhil, please see the updated answer below. I was able to reproduce with the code from the repo that you prepared and shared. The problem should be solved now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finally, the solution!..

**You're making a call to `owner()`, but the contract you call is the `msg.sender`, who is just a Hardhat mock EOA. (`Certification(msg.sender).owner()::Institution.sol:L111`)**

To fix that, **make sure** the caller of `getInstitution()` in the `Institution-test.js` is an instance of the `Certification` contract, and has an `owner()` public method (*or, alternatively, a public `address owner` storage slot*).

Your logic is incorrect here:

```js
const institute_data = await institution.getInstituteData(
  mockInstitute_acc.address
  // { from: await certification.getAddress() }
);
```

You should send the `getInstituteData(...)` transaction from the Certification contract.

You can do something like that:

```
contract Certification {
// ...

function getInstituteData(address institutionAddress) external view returns (
            string memory instituteName,
            string memory instituteAcronym,
            string memory instituteLink,
            Institution.Course[] memory instituteCourses
        ) {
            (instituteName, instituteAcronym, instituteLink, instituteCourses) = institution.getInstituteData(institutionAddress);
        }

// ...
}
```

*(in `Certification.sol`)*

---

And then this code will *(finally!)* work!

```js
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Institution Contract", function () {
  let mockOwner_acc,
    mockInstitute_acc,
    mockInvalid_acc,
    mockInstitute,
    mockInstituteCourses,
    institution,
    certification;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    mockOwner_acc = accounts[0];
    mockInstitute_acc = accounts[1];
    mockInvalid_acc = accounts[2];

    mockInstitute = {
      institute_name: "Heritage Institute of Technology",
      institute_acronym: "HITK",
      institute_link: "www.heritageit.edu",
    };

    mockInstituteCourses = [
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Engineering",
        course_code: "CSE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Electronics and Communication Engineering",
        course_code: "ECE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Business Studies",
        course_code: "CSBS",
      },
    ];

    const Institution = await ethers.getContractFactory("Institution");
    institution = await Institution.deploy({
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });

    institution_address = await institution.getAddress();

    const Certification = await ethers.getContractFactory("Certification");
    certification = await Certification.deploy(await institution.getAddress(), {
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });

    // console.log('Address:', await certification.getAddress());
  });

  describe("Deployment of Institution Contract", () => {
    it("It has correct owner", async function () {
      const instituteContract_owner = await institution.owner();
      assert.equal(instituteContract_owner, mockOwner_acc.address);
    });
  });

  describe("Adding institute", () => {
    it("Only owner can add Institute, others cannot add", async function () {
      const attackerConnectedAccounts = await institution.connect(
        mockInvalid_acc
      );
      await expect(
        attackerConnectedAccounts.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstituteCourses
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(attackerConnectedAccounts, "NotOwner");
    });

    it("Adds an institute with valid details", async function () {
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstituteCourses,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      const { events, logs } = await receipt.wait();

      // console.log(logs[0].fragment.name);
      // console.log(logs[0].args._instituteName);

      assert.equal(logs.length, 1);
      assert.equal(logs[0].fragment.name, "instituteAdded");
      assert.equal(logs[0].args._instituteName, mockInstitute.institute_name);

      const institute_data = await certification.getInstituteData(
            mockInstitute_acc.address
          );

          console.log({institute_data})
          // console.log({institute_data})
          assert.equal(institute_data[0], mockInstitute.institute_name);
          assert.equal(institute_data[1], mockInstitute.institute_acronym);
          assert.equal(institute_data[2], mockInstitute.institute_link);
  
          console.log('3', institute_data[3])

          const formattedInstituteMockCoursesData = mockInstituteCourses.map((x) => {
            return { course_name: x.course_name };
          });

          // ! THERE'S NO COURSE_CODE in the Institution.sol::Course struct, contrary to the 
          const formattedInstituteCoursesData = mockInstituteCourses.map((x) => {
            return { course_name: x.course_name };
          });
      
          assert.equal(
            JSON.stringify(formattedInstituteCoursesData),
            JSON.stringify(formattedInstituteMockCoursesData),
            "the courses of the institute is incorrect"
          );
    });

    it("Fails if Institute already existed", async function () {
      // const institution2 = await Institution.new({ from: mockOwner_acc });
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstituteCourses,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstituteCourses,
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Institute with token already exists");
    });

    it("Checks atleast one course is added or not", async function () {
      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          [],
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Atleast one course must be added");
    });
  });
});
```

---

You can see I added this line to your test file instead to get the recorded institution data:

```js
// THIS ONE below!!! ::
const institute_data = await certification.getInstituteData(
            mockInstitute_acc.address
          );

// other test case logic implemented

          console.log({institute_data})
          // console.log({institute_data})
          assert.equal(institute_data[0], mockInstitute.institute_name);
          assert.equal(institute_data[1], mockInstitute.institute_acronym);
          assert.equal(institute_data[2], mockInstitute.institute_link);
  
          console.log('3', institute_data[3])

          const formattedInstituteMockCoursesData = mockInstituteCourses.map((x) => {
            return { course_name: x.course_name };
          });

          // ! THERE'S NO COURSE_CODE in the Institution.sol::Course struct, contrary to the 
          const formattedInstituteCoursesData = mockInstituteCourses.map((x) => {
            return { course_name: x.course_name };
          });
      
          assert.equal(
            JSON.stringify(formattedInstituteCoursesData),
            JSON.stringify(formattedInstituteMockCoursesData),
            "the courses of the institute is incorrect"
          );
```

#### Voilà!

P.S. Here's the `Institution.sol`, slightly updated:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

import "./Certification.sol";

error NotOwner();

contract Institution {
    // State Variables
    address public owner;

    // Mappings
    mapping(address => Institute) public institutes; // Institutes Mapping
    mapping(address => Course[]) public instituteCourses; // Courses Mapping

    // Events
    event instituteAdded(string _instituteName);

    // Modifier
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Course {
        string course_name;
        // Other attributes can be added
    }

    struct Institute {
        string institute_name;
        string institute_acronym;
        string institute_link;
    }

    function stringToBytes32(
        string memory source
    ) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }

    function addInstitute(
        address _address,
        string memory _institute_name,
        string memory _institute_acronym,
        string memory _institute_link,
        Course[] memory _institute_courses
    ) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(
            institutes[_address].institute_name
        );
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length == 0,
            "Institute with token already exists"
        );
        require(
            _institute_courses.length > 0,
            "Atleast one course must be added"
        );
        institutes[_address] = Institute(
            _institute_name,
            _institute_acronym,
            _institute_link
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _institute_courses.length; i++) {
            instituteCourses[_address].push(_institute_courses[i]);
        }

        emit instituteAdded(_institute_name);
    }

    // Called by Institutions
    // function getInstituteData()
    //     public
    //     view
    //     returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    // {
    //     Institute memory temp = institutes[msg.sender];
    //     bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
    //     require(
    //         tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
    //         "Institute account does not exist!"
    //     );
    //     return (
    //         temp.institute_name,
    //         temp.institute_acronym,
    //         temp.institute_link,
    //         instituteCourses[msg.sender]
    //     );
    // }

    // Called by Smart Contracts
    function getInstituteData(
        address _address
    )
        public
        view
        returns (string memory instituteName, string memory instituteAcronym, string memory instituteLink, Course[] memory courses)
    {
        require(
            Certification(msg.sender).owner() == owner,
            "Incorrect smart contract & authorizations!"
        );

        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
            "Institute does not exist!"
        );


        instituteName = temp.institute_name;
        instituteAcronym = temp.institute_acronym;
        instituteLink = temp.institute_link;
        courses = instituteCourses[_address];
    }

    function checkInstitutePermission(
        address _address
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        if (tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*(My first, old suggestions, for record:)*

The revert reason you've been getting is just a problem with how Hardhat interprets the reverted `getInstituteData` transaction.

There's a root problem with your test file.

- You need to make sure the `getInstituteData` call is run only **AFTER** the *institution with the key of `mockInstitute_acc.address`* has been added to the storage (with `addInstitute`) *[which basically means that the test case with `getInstituteData` will **NOT** get run *asynchronously* anymore, and will wait for `addInstitute` to get mined]*

You can use the `after([name of the "it" label that is used for the pre-hook function], fn() {...})` Mocha utility to achieve the correct result.

Here's the fixed test code with all of the test cases passing properly:

```js
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Institution Contract", function () {
  let mockOwner_acc,
    mockInstitute_acc,
    mockInvalid_acc,
    mockInstitute,
    mockInstitute_course,
    institution,
    certification;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    mockOwner_acc = accounts[0];
    mockInstitute_acc = accounts[1];
    mockInvalid_acc = accounts[2];

    mockInstitute = {
      institute_name: "Heritage Institute of Technology",
      institute_acronym: "HITK",
      institute_link: "www.heritageit.edu",
    };

    mockInstitute_course = [
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Engineering",
        course_code: "CSE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Electronics and Communication Engineering",
        course_code: "ECE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Business Studies",
        course_code: "CSBS",
      },
    ];

    const Institution = await ethers.getContractFactory("Institution");

    institution = await Institution.deploy({ from: mockOwner_acc });

    await institution.waitForDeployment();

    institution_address = await institution.getAddress();

    const Certification = await ethers.getContractFactory("Certification");
    certification = await Certification.deploy(await institution.getAddress(), {
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });

    await certification.waitForDeployment();
  });

  describe("Deployment of Institution Contract", () => {
    it("It has correct owner", async function () {
      const instituteContract_owner = await institution.owner();
      assert.equal(instituteContract_owner, mockOwner_acc.address);
    });
  });

  describe("Adding institute", () => {
    // HERE'S THAT IMPORTANT CHANGE!
    after('Only owner can add Institute, others cannot add', function () {
      it("Only owner can request for Institute Data", async function () {
        const instituteData = await institution.getInstituteData(
          mockInstitute_acc.address
        );
      });
    });
    it("Only owner can add Institute, others cannot add", async function () {
      const attackerConnectedAccounts = await institution.connect(
        mockInvalid_acc
      );
      await expect(
        attackerConnectedAccounts.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstitute_course
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(attackerConnectedAccounts, "NotOwner");
    });

    it("Adds an institute with valid details", async function () {
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      const { logs } = await receipt.wait();

      console.log(logs[0].fragment.name);
      console.log(logs[0].args._instituteName);

      assert.equal(logs.length, 1);
      assert.equal(logs[0].fragment.name, "instituteAdded");
      assert.equal(logs[0].args._instituteName, mockInstitute.institute_name);
    });

    it("Fails if an institute already exists", async function () {
      // const institution2 = await Institution.new({ from: mockOwner_acc });
      await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstitute_course,
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Institute with token already exists");
    });

    it("Checks at least one course is added or not", async function () {
      await expect(
        institution.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          [],
          { from: mockOwner_acc }
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Atleast one course must be added");
    });
  });
});
```

---

Hopefully, that answers your question.

---

**Notes:**

- This applies to your particular case, but generally <s>[as far as I'm aware]</s> the `function returned an unexpected amount of data` error is thrown either if the actual ABI of the called contract doesn't match with the ABI that you reference when instantiating a contract in your Hardhat file ***BECAUSE IT WAS CACHED FROM A PREVIOUS COMPILATION***
- Or if you call the **WRONG** contract with the ABI *different* from the actual ABI

So please check both cases, if you're stumbled upon this error :)

---

P.S. The test file works for me with this smart contract (I must admit I improvised with the `Certification` contract, because *you* didn't attach it in the question, but I believe it doesn't make a big difference anyways)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

contract Certification {
    address public owner;

    constructor(address) {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

error NotOwner();

contract Institution {
    // State Variables
    address public owner;

    // Mappings
    mapping(address => Institute) private institutes; // Institutes Mapping
    mapping(address => Course[]) private instituteCourses; // Courses Mapping

    // Events
    event instituteAdded(string _instituteName);

    // Modifier
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Course {
        string course_name;
        string course_code;
        // Other attributes can be added
    }

    struct Institute {
        string institute_name;
        string institute_acronym;
        string institute_link;
    }

    function stringToBytes32(
        string memory source
    ) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }

    function addInstitute(
        address _address,
        string memory _institute_name,
        string memory _institute_acronym,
        string memory _institute_link,
        Course[] memory _institute_courses
    ) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(
            institutes[_address].institute_name
        );
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length == 0,
            "Institute with token already exists"
        );
        require(
            _institute_courses.length > 0,
            "Atleast one course must be added"
        );
        institutes[_address] = Institute(
            _institute_name,
            _institute_acronym,
            _institute_link
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _institute_courses.length; i++) {
            instituteCourses[_address].push(_institute_courses[i]);
        }

        emit instituteAdded(_institute_name);
    }

    // Called by Institutions
    // function getInstituteData()
    //     public
    //     view
    //     returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    // {
    //     Institute memory temp = institutes[msg.sender];
    //     bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
    //     require(
    //         tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
    //         "Institute account does not exist!"
    //     );
    //     return (
    //         temp.institute_name,
    //         temp.institute_acronym,
    //         temp.institute_link,
    //         instituteCourses[msg.sender]
    //     );
    // }

    // Called by Smart Contracts
    function getInstituteData(
        address _address
    )
        public
        view
        returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    {
        /**require(
            Certification(msg.sender).owner() == owner,
            "Incorrect smart contract & authorizations!"
        ); - removed for testing **/
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
            "Institute does not exist!"
        );
        return (
            temp.institute_name,
            temp.institute_acronym,
            temp.institute_link,
            instituteCourses[_address]
        );
    }

    function checkInstitutePermission(
        address _address
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        if (tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### It even makes more sense to use `after(..., ...)` *semantically*, because if the `addInstitute` test case fails for some reason, you don't want to check `getInstitute`, do you?

---

*(Edit: Can you check here?)*

[image: hardhat-chaia-abi-function-returned-an-unexpected-amount-of-data]

Comment: I am getting error with describe("Fetching the Institute Data") only. And all the code apart from this is correct as it is not giving any problem after removing the given describe.

Comment: Oh, so to clarify: *doesn't the code I shared above in my post work for you?* **Could you also check the `artifacts/` directory and confirm whether the `Institution.json` has the correct ABI return types for the `getInstitute` function?**

Comment: Yaah it has correct abi return. I have checked my abi it is same as yous in the pic.

Comment: But it is giving me same error can you help me

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I'll get back to you today or tomorrow when I have free time after my 9/5 work, and will try to help you. :)

Comment: @NikhilRaj, can you attach your Hardhat file contents too?

Comment: I have uploaded my code to github repo with the url "https://github.com/nraj07054/Blockchain-Certificate-Verification-System".
So can you check it and guide me

Comment: @NikhilRaj, you can find the solution in my updated answer, and also here on GitHub: https://github.com/milaabl/hardhat-reverted-function-returned-an-unexpected-amount-of-data

Comment: In your code you have called getInstituteData in addInstitute part, but in my code I have created another describe() block. Can you tell me what's the problem in creating another describe block()

Comment: There's a root problem with your test file.

You need to make sure the getInstituteData call is run only AFTER the institution with the key of mockInstitute_acc.address has been added to the storage (with addInstitute) [which basically means that the test case with getInstituteData will NOT get run asynchronously anymore, and will wait for addInstitute to get mined]
You can use the after([name of the "it" label that is used for the pre-hook function], fn() {...}) Mocha utility to achieve the correct result. Mocha by default runs **sibling** tests asynchronously.

Comment: @NikhilRaj, is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for so much help. Now its clear

Comment: @NikhilRaj, then please accept my answer if it was helpful!! :)